# how do i use a boolean field in django-haystack search query

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack to power search for my application and I have boolean fields i would like to filter my models by. However, when I try doing this, my search query fails.

The search backend i'm using is elasticsearch

Answer (score 5):

Posting some of your code here would be helpful in figuring out what is going wrong for you, as it's hard to troubleshoot with nothing.

How I implemented this (using whoosh rather than elasticsearch, but the django code should be the same/similar at any rate) was like so:

created my own searchform class (if you haven't already done this, look at [Haystack Docs - Creating your own form](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html#creating-your-own-form)

```
from django import forms
from haystack.forms import SearchForm

class PaidPropertySearchForm(SearchForm):
    q = forms.CharField(required=False, label=('Town Area'))
    #othersearchtermshere
    furnished = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(PaidPropertySearchForm, self).search()
        #other search filtering here
        if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['furnished']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(furnished__contains=self.cleaned_data['furnished'])

        return sqs
```

relevant model field is simply:

```
class Properties (models.Model):.
    furnished = models.BooleanField()
```

and my searchindexes.py:

```
class PropertyIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    #other indexed terms
    furnished = indexes.BooleanField(model_attr='furnished', default='false')
```

Here it's worth noting that there are some issues between haystack and the whoosh backend with boolean values, that required me to specify the defult index value as a string 'false' rather than the boolean value False. If i didn't do this or didn't set a default, for some reason ALL boolean values were indexed as True, regardless of what the model had stored. I don't know if that issue would affect elasticsearch, so you may not need

```
default='false'
```

in your search index

Hopefully this helps get you on the right track if you haven't already figured it out.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the bit about Whoosh: I'm using it locally because I'm lazy and I've been going nuts for a while here (though I have yet to get rid of that behavior even using `default='false'`).

Comment: I had the same problem with Elasticsearch, and this fixed it for me. It's also important to note that you CAN NOT filter using an actual boolean value...which is sort of dumb. You HAVE to use either 'true' or 'false'. e.g. sqs = sqs.filter(mybool='true'). Using True or False will behave like 'true', which really feels like a horrible design if not an outright bug.

Answer (score 4):

```
sqs = sqs.filter(boolean_field=True)
```

did not work for me either (using Haystack 2.1.0 and Elasticsearch 1.2.1) but

```
sqs = sqs.filter(boolean_field=1)
```

did.